# Docker MySQL shutdown immediately after startup, no visible errors in logs

Tags: mysql, docker, startup

I follow the instructions on the Docker Hub MySQL page (https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) by running the command (excluding the `$`)

```
$ docker run --name mysql8016 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password1 -d mysql:8.0.16
```

After pulling the images, the container seems to start but then immediately shuts down. This is the log I read from `docker container logs mysql8016`:

```
Initializing database
2019-12-10T00:51:09.949734Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-12-10T00:51:09.949862Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server in progress as process 27
2019-12-10T00:51:19.627834Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2019-12-10T00:51:30.920219Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) initializing of server has completed
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
MySQL init process in progress...
2019-12-10T00:51:33.618057Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-12-10T00:51:33.618660Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 78
2019-12-10T00:51:36.468597Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-12-10T00:51:36.480371Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-12-10T00:51:36.611544Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-12-10T00:51:36.772724Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2019-12-10T00:52:07.732230911Z 
2019-12-10T00:52:09.583342Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-12-10T00:52:09.649848201Z 
MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
2019-12-10T00:52:09.650010601Z 
2019-12-10T00:52:10.213653Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-12-10T00:52:10.213854Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
2019-12-10T00:52:12.183920Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-12-10T00:52:12.192385Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-12-10T00:52:12.342685Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.16'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-12-10T00:52:12.529767Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

As the logs do not contain any visible errors, I'm not sure if any of those warnings are enough to cause the immediate shutdown, not sure how to go about fixing this.

Comment: The container seems up and running from the logs

Comment: Why do you think it has shut down?

Comment: This says `2019-12-10T00:52:09.583342Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.` Also, when I checked with `docker ps -a`, my container did not show up as healthy.

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari I don't recall fixing this, but I think I reinstalled my Docker engine due to another problem; I didn't encounter this problem again.