# MySql Server shut down immediately after docker-compose up

Tags: mysql, docker

This is my docker-compose file. When I execute sudo docker-compose up I got an error on mysql server.

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '8080:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - mailhog
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailhog:
        image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
```

This is what I am getting in terminal:

```
ech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.458966Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.460098Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.32) starting as process 1
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.465939Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.562068Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.743847Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.743907Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.744467Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010259] [Server] Another process with pid 62 is using unix socket file.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.744489Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010268] [Server] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:34.744503Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
tech-hub-api-mysql-1    | 2023-01-26T06:43:36.299171Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.32)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
tech-hub-api-mysql-1 exited with code 1
```

any advice?
Thanks.

I tried re-configuring mysql and docker. On other machines  the file works itself. Then I tried re-installing mysql. Did not work.

Comment: Related, possibly a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59258836/14853083

Comment: `Another process with pid 62 is using unix socket file.`. Also, why on earth are you running Docker with sudo?

Comment: What is in the `create-testing-database.sh` script?

Comment: @BoristheSpider  I tried those commands to remove every process: 
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
But it did not work. Any suggestion?

Comment: @DavidMaze This came with default when I installed Laravel Sail Project. create-testing-database.sh is empty.

Comment: Did you solve it ? I'm having same problem for 3 days.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I created a new project with `laravel-build`. I solved this by simply renaming all related volume names since I have more than one Laravel Sail project.

So, instead of the default one for MySQL

```yaml
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - mysqladmin
            - ping
            - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

I used this one (check `volumes` section)

```yaml
mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
        - 'project-name-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
    networks:
        - project-name
    healthcheck:
        test:
            - CMD
            - mysqladmin
            - ping
            - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
        retries: 3
        timeout: 5s
```

Hope it will help someone

**UPD**:
Actually, the thing which helped me is just deleting the volume, I realized it later when I found out that my previous volume was still in the list (`sail-mysql`).